# How to disable kernel module signing in Android by adb

Tags: android, linux, security, module, linux-kernel

Kernel module signing protects the kernel from all the modules that are loaded into the kernel during runtime.
In Android, all the modules under /system/lib/modules must be checked before load, the signing key is generated while compiling, so the output of different developer is signing different. When flash **system.img** and **boot.img** from different developer into device, **modules under /system/lib/modules cannot load**.

To disable module signing, we can simply disable:

- CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=y  Enables the kernel module signing feature. With
  this master flag, key generation is enabled and public key is
  embedded into the kernel. If this flag is disabled, none of the
  following flags have any effect.
- CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL=y  Signs all the modules present in the build
  during build compilation.
- CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_FORCE=y Enforces loading only the modules (signed
  with the correct key) on the target; the rest of the modules are
  rejected.

And then recompile kernel. But I want to know, **if I have the root privilege, can I disable the security feature in Android by adb shell**?  this is more convenient.